# how does second recursive that is return numberOfPaths(m-1, n) + numberOfPaths(m, n-1) call works?

Tags: recursion

How does  second recursive that is  return  numberOfPaths(m-1, n) + numberOfPaths(m, n-1) call works??

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Returns count of possible paths to reach cell at row number m and column
// number n from the topmost leftmost cell (cell at 1, 1)
int  numberOfPaths(int m, int n)
{
   // If either given row number is first or given column number is first
   if (m == 1 || n == 1)
        return 1;

   // If diagonal movements are allowed then the last addition
   // is required.
   return  numberOfPaths(m-1, n) + numberOfPaths(m, n-1);
           // + numberOfPaths(m-1,n-1);
}

int main()
{
    cout << numberOfPaths(3, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It calls the function `numberOfPaths` again. Once with `m-1` and `n` and once with `m` and `n-1` and adds their results.

If you called `numberOfPaths(2,2)` it would call `numberOfPaths(1,2)` and `numberOfPaths(2,1)` which both return `1` and thus `numberOfPaths(2,2)` would return `2`.

Comment: please explain with case m=3 and n=3? i

Comment: What do you not understand?